# Interpreting interactions in linear mixed effect model using lmer

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, interaction

I am building a linear mixed effect model using the lmer function from the lme4 package in R but I am struggling to interpret the interactions terms in the model. I have used the following syntax:

```
mod2 <- lmer(post.diff ~ #my predicted DV
            course * group
             #my fixed effects
             + (1|bib)
             #my random effects
             , dat, REML = FALSE)
```

The two factors - course and group - are dummy coded variables. This gives me the following output:

```
Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -0.26080    0.18036 56.22506  -1.446    0.154    
courseB         0.87647    0.09257 94.00000   9.468 2.49e-15 ***
courseC         2.38860    0.09257 94.00000  25.802  < 2e-16 ***
group1         -0.20996    0.26361 56.22506  -0.796    0.429    
courseB:group1  0.09664    0.13531 94.00000   0.714    0.477    
courseC:group1  0.10678    0.13531 94.00000   0.789    0.432
```

Using the anova() function, I can see that there is no main effect of group nor any interactions:

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
              Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF  F value Pr(>F)    
course       142.305  71.152     2    94 664.1974 <2e-16 ***
group          0.034   0.034     1    47   0.3188 0.5750    
course:group   0.081   0.041     2    94   0.3795 0.6853
```

Still, I want to better understand how I can interpret the output from my model. From my understanding:

**-0.26080** (intercept) is the estimated mean for the group codes with 0 in course A

**0.87647** is the estimated simple slope for the group codes with 0 in course B

**2.38860** is the estimated simple slope for the group codes with 0 in course C

**-0.20996** is the estimated simple slope for the group codes with 1 in course A

My question is how I should interpret the interactions terms in the model. I hope someone can help me so that I can see it an equation form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to change the terminology a bit as I find that talking consistently and explicitly about coefficients representing *differences* in associations with outcome under treatment/dummy coding help a lot when you get to the level of interactions. I'll keep your interpretation of the intercept, but from there on I recommend saying:

0.87647 is the estimated difference between `course B` and `course A` for `group 0`;

2.38860 is the estimated difference between `course C` and `course A`  for `group 0`;

-0.20996 is the estimated difference between `group 1` and `group 0`  in `course A`.

Then the interpretation of interaction coefficients is just in terms of the next level of *differences* in estimates.

The `courseB:group1` interaction of  0.09664 is the *extra estimated difference* from `course A` and `group 0` *beyond* the sum of individual differences associated with `group B` and `group 1` above, and:

the `courseC:group1` interaction of  0.10678 is the *extra estimated difference* from `course A` and `group 0` *beyond* the sum of individual differences associated with `group C` and `group 1` above.

Some find that writing things out explicitly in terms of the 0/1 False/True entries used in the dummy-coded design matrix helps with understanding. For fixed effects you have the following model, with 0/1 coding except for `intercept`, and `*` representing actual multiplication (not the R expansion into individual and interaction terms):

```
outcome ~ intercept + isCourseB + isCourseC + isGroup1 + (isCourseB * isGroup1) + (isCourseC * isGroup1)
```

with the corresponding coefficients in the order shown in your summary display. Each interaction term is non-zero only when both of the individual dummy codings is non-zero. Reading left to right shows how each coefficient represents a *difference* from what had already been predicted. This can extend to higher-order interactions if present in a model.